# Retrieve certain fields from a table using a column value where table name is unknown

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the cost and itemno of a product which I get dynamically from the user.  So I don't know under what table the product is present.

```
SELECT cost,itemno FROM inde.columns WHERE column_name ='previousItems';
```

Where `inde` is the schema name and `previousitem` is the product name which i get dynamically from the user in a jsp.
I get the error message as sql syntax wrong.The following is the error message

> javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
>       MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: this is a simple syntax error. Remove last ')' and delete this question.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad,i added the ')' by mistake here.

Comment: Your error message does not match your query. After fixing the query, do you still have a problem or are you OK now? Please update the question so that it is internally consistent.

Answer (score 0):

replave your query by this

```
    SELECT cost,itemno FROM inde WHERE column_name ='previousItems';
```

this if `inde` is the name of the table

Answer (score 0):

You can search unknown tables by column name with below query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('COLOM_NAME_TO_SEARCH')
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YOUR_DATABASE_NAME';
```